# Is CaaS a certain type of PaaS?

Tags: cloud, paas

I've recently asked myself if Container as a Service was a certain type of Platform as a Service or not. Is a Container a Platform ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PaaS and CaaS are two different things.

On a PaaS, you only run your code in a cartridge (which can be a VM or even a container) but you'll only be able to run code that is supported by your PaaS provider.
You won't be able to modify the OS on which your code is running.
Example: Heroku

On a CaaS, you will be able to run a container and you won't be limited by the languages supported by your PaaS provider. You can run anything you want in your container as long as the container engine is supported by your CaaS provider.
Example: Amazon Container Services (ECS)

CaaS falls somewhere between Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) and Platform as a Service (PaaS).

Check this for more informations : http://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/definition/Containers-as-a-Service-CaaS

Comment: And what if CaaS is a sort of IaaS ?

Comment: CaaS is actually between PaaS and IaaS.

I would even say that in long term, I would see CaaS replacing IaaS.